# Nested Array in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested

Hello im trying to append the media size for my image set so the first image should have the mediaSize 768px the second 1024 and so on, how can i wrap it up. i would like to use the values for my srcset : to set the min width for media.

here is my Object

```
    data = {[
  {
    thumbnail: 'http://via.placeholder.com/90x90',
    images:
    [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/768x400',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/1024x400',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/1999x400',
      {mediaSize : [ "768px", "1024px","1999px "]}
    ]
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var data = [
   {
       'thumbnail': 'http://via.placeholder.com/90x90',
       'images':
        [
           { 'link': 'http://via.placeholder.com/768x400' },
           { 'link1': 'http://via.placeholder.com/1024x400' },
           { 'link2': 'http://via.placeholder.com/1999x400' },

          {
              'mediaSize': [
                 { 'id': "768px" },
                 { 'id1': "1024px" },
                 { 'id2': "1999px" },
              ]
          },
        ]
   }
        ]
```

check this....

```
   var data = [
    {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Soler Power Plant",
        "CategoryProducts": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": 'Commercial Solar Power Plant',
            "SubTitle": 'Eco, Eco Friendly, Energy, Green, Solar',
            "Brand": 'ACS',
            "Usage": '',
            "Type": '',
            "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
            "Body_Material": '',
            "Description": 'Having a pre-determined quality administration system, we are thoroughly involved in delivering Commercial Solar Power Plant.',
            "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Sola-power-plant.jpg',
        }]
    }]
```